# issue while outputting the image in code igniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, foreach

I'm new to code igniter and learning with how to display images in html page. But the images displays file but it also displays the image tags `alt=""` also. Here is  my code.

views/admin.php

```
<div class="row">
        <?php   
            //print_r($images_disp);
            
            foreach($images_disp as $item=>$val){
        ?>  
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url().''.$val['imagepath'];?>" width="150px" height="150px" alt="'<?php echo $val['name']?>'" >
                </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </div>
```

controller/AddProduct_controller

```
 public function index(){
        $sql['images_disp'] = $this->addProduct_model->show_images();
        /* echo "<pre>";
        print_r($sql);
        echo "</pre>"; */
        $this->load->view('admin',$sql);
    }
```

model/AddProduct_model

```
public function show_images(){
    $query = $this->db->get('db_images');
    $query = $query->result_array();
    
    return $query;
}
```

HERE IS THE ISSUE IN BELOW IMAGE
[OUTPUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbo8T.png)

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: It looks like there is are quotes in the name field. That is causing the alt property in the img tag to be closed. So everything that follows the quote will be displayed in the view. If the quotes do need to be there, some encoding may help, or possibly escaping

Comment: You need to remove single quotes in ```alt``` tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario name column contains double quotes(") which is causing problem in echo statement. Double quotes causing `alt` attribute value issue.
Replace your line of code with this line :

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().''.$val['imagepath'];?>" width="150px" height="150px" alt="'<?php echo html_escape($val['name']); ?>'" >
```

**[html_escape](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=html_escape#html_escape)** will escape the html character from your string.
**Advice :**
Always avoid inserting quotes and other character directly in database, escape user input before inserting in database.

At time of insert escape user input like this.

```
$escaped_str =  $this->db->escape($input_str);
```

**[$this->db->escape()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html?highlight=escape#escaping-queries)** method will escape all the quotes from your string.

Comment: still the error is their here is the [image link](https://ibb.co/gZenFv)

Comment: can you just post what output you are getting now.

Comment: i have given it in above image link

Comment: `html_escape($val['name']);` WORKS THANKS

Comment: Great to hear that mate ☺️ You can up vote my answer also.. 

Comment: Advice.. Always parse input date when it is coming from user.. This will prevent you from xss and other issues. Thanks ☺️

Comment: it is showing cannot up vote becoz i have less than 15 reputation.